# How to get laser data in gazebo?

Tags: ros, gazebo, path, position, planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone
I have created my diff drive robot and also mounted laser on the robot using Hokuyo model. Now I need to move my robot from start position to the goal position. I can't understand how to do this. Please help I am beginner.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246475/how-to-get-laser-data-in-gazebo?/) by [xeeshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28330/xeeshan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-10-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rachit Khurana](https://answers.ros.org/users/28351/rachit-khurana/) on 2016-10-26**:
How have you specified the start and goal position?

**Comment by [Rachit Khurana](https://answers.ros.org/users/28351/rachit-khurana/) on 2016-10-26**:
Try https://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/husky/HuskyMove.html. It is a husky tutorial which proves a nice way to move from start to goal.

**Comment by [xeeshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28330/xeeshan/) on 2016-10-27**:
I have already followed this but helps nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gazebo should automatically publish laser scan data. Use `$  rostopic list` to find the name of that topic.

The simplest way would be to publish your wheel velocity to `/cmd_vel` and by trial and error check if you have reached your goal.

If this is very inefficient for you then I would suggest you look at the ROS Navigation stack. Classify your problem according to the tools the stack offers.

---

Originally posted by [arttp2](https://answers.ros.org/users/24037/arttp2/) with karma: 123 on 2016-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xeeshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28330/xeeshan/) on 2016-10-27**:
Thanks for answering my questions.
This is already working using /cmd_vel and using teleop. Basically I want to move my robot between two fixed points set by me. before this how I can check that my laser is working? It's just showing blue light in the simulator.

**Comment by [arttp2](https://answers.ros.org/users/24037/arttp2/) on 2016-10-27**:
Do you want your robot to move in straight line between start to goal? Probably not.

```
 $ rostopic list
```

This command will display the name of the topic where Gazebo is publishing laser scan data. Subscribe it in a node. Use it to guide your robot by giving appropriate /cmd_vel values.

**Comment by [arttp2](https://answers.ros.org/users/24037/arttp2/) on 2016-10-27**:
If you are not able to achieve your targets this way, then read this: [Navigation](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation)

It has a steep learning curve.

**Comment by [xeeshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28330/xeeshan/) on 2016-10-28**:
I have mounted laser on my diff drive robot using hokuyo model. But I am unable to find the laser scanner node. I have read various forums that suggest me to make URDF of my robot and then use necessary plugins after that I have to set the node in RVIZ. I am confused with RVIZ why should we use that

**Comment by [xeeshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28330/xeeshan/) on 2016-10-28**:
after all I am working in gazebo